# Can one extract model fit parameters after a ggplot stat_smooth call?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

Using `stat_smooth`, I can fit models to data. E.g.

```
g=ggplot(tips,aes(x=tip,y=as.numeric(unclass(factor(tips$sex))-1))) +facet_grid(time~.) 
g=g+ stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point") 
g=g+ stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial")
```

I would like to know the coefficients of the glm binomial fits. I could re-do the fit with `dlply` and get the coefficients with `ldply`, but I'd like to avoid such duplication.

Calling `str(g)` reveals the hierarchy of objects that `ggplot2` creates, perhaps there's some way to get to the coefficients through that?

Comment: P.S. is there a better way to change sex to a number besides the as.numeric etc. method above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the models are only created when the plot is rendered. However, it's usually pretty easy to do it yourself with `plyr`.

Why do you want to convert sex to a number?  Using `as.numeric` should be enough by itself, but if you're going to do the subtraction in the model you'll need to surround it with `I()`.

Comment: Is there a chance we could see how this is done with plyr? I have the same question, but no idea where to start. Thanks!