# Capture stat_smooth data or parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, gam, loess

I'm plotting with `ggplot2` and I would like to know if there is a way to capture the points generated by `stat_smooth` or at least know what parameters it used.

```
    ggplot(data=ICLR, aes(x=  AÑO_MES, y=  ICLRr, size=PatMensualFondo ))  + 
    xlab("Patrimonio Medio") + ylab("% Cobertura Media") + 
    stat_smooth( mapping = aes (group = 1)) +
    geom_point()
```

For more than 1000 points I get this : `" geom_smooth: method="auto" and size of largest group is >=1000, so using gam with formula: y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"). Use 'method = x' to change the smoothing method. "` I know that it used `gam method` , but what else ?

If I can't capture data points as it is said in this thread :

[Can one extract model fit parameters after a ggplot stat_smooth call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666805/can-one-extract-model-fit-parameters-after-a-ggplot-stat-smooth-call)

How can I replicate what stat_smooth did ?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9789871/269476

Comment: Cool...didn't see that one...thx