# Extracting facetedn lm models from ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I want to extract the linear models given by the ggplot2.
Is there a better way to extract these models instead of re-running the individual model separately?

Below is a reproducible code. However, note that Ecdat package is quite big.

```
library(ggplot2);library(Ecdat)
data('Housing') # from Ecdat
ggplot(Housing, aes(lotsize, price, color = airco, fill = airco)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
  ggtitle('Price (lotsize)') + facet_grid( . ~ airco, margins = T) + theme_classic()
```

Below is the visual output from ggplot. You may notice that we have 3 different models below. I would like to extract the 3 models for further analysis instead of rerunning them with lm().

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It seems this is [not currently possible](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/491) and appears to be by design. I however think there should be a way to get "backend" and extract the models. See what hadley had to say back [then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2667343/10323798).

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon, thanks for the link, I guess from Hadley comment, it's not something they would work on. It's ok then, I just rerun the model separately to get the coeffs. Should I close this question or leave it as it is?

Comment: I think you should leave the question as is. Chances are someone might have thought of a way to do it or one may come across it and think it would be something cool to implement.