# Same parameters from lm() and geom_smooth()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering if the function `lm()` from the stats package is the same as the one used in `geom_smoot(method = lm)` in ggplot2. 
If so, are the parameters calculated by them the same everytime for the same data.

So would...

```
lm(response ~ variable, data = dat)
```

calculate the same parameters as...

```
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, response)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear model (coded in `lm`) is fully deterministic. It returns the same results as long as you call it on the same input. `geom_smooth` uses `stats::lm` behind the scene, so the results should be the same. Note that it is not possible to extract model parameters from a `ggplot` plot ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666805/can-one-extract-model-fit-parameters-after-a-ggplot-stat-smooth-call)).

Comment: Thank you very much. I know that I cannot extract the parameters from ggplot. Thats why I just wanted to do the same model externally and use the parameters of that one. I just wanted to be sure, that the parameters I am going to report are the same parameters that I show in my plot.

Comment: You can get and print the equation and R^2 on the plot using stat_poly_eq from ggpmisc if that helps?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `geom_smooth` uses `stats::lm`. The`?geom_smooth` documentation mentions `stats::lm` specifically, and in the *See Also* section has a link to the `lm` documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I just found it in the documentation myself. Still I was not sure if the lm() function returns the same results everytime.

Comment: It does. Linear models are deterministic. You can see the [wikipedia page on linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_model) for an introduction.